# Program crashes in debug mode: "unable to demangle"?

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, demangler

In Eclipse CDT my code does not run in debug mode. I get the following message:

/build/gdb-HnfxP_/gdb-7.10/gdb/cp-support.c:1595: demangler-warning: unable to demangle '_ZdvI7Vector3dESt6vectorIDTdvcvT__EcvT0__EESaIS4_EERKS1_IS2_SaIS2_EERKS1_IS3_SaIS3_EE' (demangler failed with signal 11)
Unable to dump core, use `ulimit -c unlimited' before executing GDB next time.

Using https://d.fuqu.jp/c++filtjs/ I found that the mangled symbol corresponds to

```
std::vector<decltype (((Vector3)())/((double)())), std::allocator<decltype (((Vector3)())/((double)()))> > operator/<Vector3, double>(std::vector<Vector3, std::allocator<Vector3> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&)
```

Why is this giving me an error and how do I fix it?

Comment: This looks like a GDB issue, consider adding an appropriate GDB tag, with  an [MCVE]. It also looks like a GDB bug, perhaps this one: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19330?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced this failure on `gdb-7.10` and can confirm that this is fixed in `gdb-7.11` and later.  I have not tracked down the exact commit that fixed this failure.

There is nothing that you can do to *fix* this issue other than upgrade to a later version of GDB.

Comment: Before I saw your answer, I came here to say the exact same thing - I upgraded to gdb-7.11 from gdb-7.10 and that fixed the issue. Thanks!